# UITableView height fit according to number of cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, height

I'm using swift 2.2 and i have a dynamic table view . I want to set table view height according to number of cell. No empty cell should display. In my current one it shows additional empty cells and heigh of table view also not dynamically changing  according to number of cells.Any help?

Comment: Refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) & [another link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052930/auto-sizing-a-uitableviewcell-swift)
hope it will helpful.

Comment: refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) & [another link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052930/auto-sizing-a-uitableviewcell-swift) hope will helpful.

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) & [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052930/auto-sizing-a-uitableviewcell-swift) will helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust the size of UITableView dynamically which would display as a non-scrollable list of content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228539/adjust-the-size-of-uitableview-dynamically-which-would-display-as-a-non-scrollab)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for not showing empty cells in tableview

```
   tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```